# PHP 8.2: Unable to read what child 15029 said into stderr: Bad file descriptor (9)

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, php-8.2

We recently upgraded our application, which is built using CodeIgniter 3, from PHP 8.0 to 8.2. However, we've been encountering persistent errors in our logs that didn't occur with PHP 8.0.

The error message is as follows:

`ERROR: unable to read what child 15029 said into stderr: Bad file descriptor (9)`

[image]

We have attempted to address this issue by modifying the following configuration values in our PHP-FPM configuration, but with no success:

- pm.max_children = 100
- pm.process_idle_timeout = 1800
- pm.max_requests = 400
- Increased max resources
- Tried increasing our ECS instance size with no luck.

In addition we have tried all the solutions (with no luck) mentioned at https://serverfault.com/questions/477786/php-fpm-bad-file-descriptor-errors

**Real-time PHP-FPM Status**

[image]

**PHP Version**
PHP 8.2.x

**Operating System**
Debian 12

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php-fpm reload "unable to read what child say"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125831/php-fpm-reload-unable-to-read-what-child-say)

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/12559 LOL, it was you?

Comment: Can you please increase pm.max_children?

Comment: Unfortunately, the changes suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125831/php-fpm-reload-unable-to-read-what-child-say are not helpful in our scenario.

For other link of PHP official repo, yes that was me :)

Comment: Did increasing `pm.max_children` help? Maybe you need a very much higher value.

Comment: There are 2 configurational changes we have made, increased ```pm.max_children``` and set ```pm.max_requests=0``` now observing them for improvement.

Comment: Just an update, we haven't observed the issue since we updated following configurations

```pm.max_children = 300```
```pm. start_servers = 50 ```
```pm. min_spare_servers = 30 ```
```pm. max_spare_servers = 50 ```
```pm. max_requests = 0 ```

Continuing to monitor the logs for a few more days.

Comment: After observing the logs for a couple of weeks, with new configurations, no new log has been found related to this issue